# Access local resources (e.g. USB devices, MS Word) from Google Web Toolkit (GWT)

Tags: macos, gwt, localhost, smartgwt

I'm considering using GWT (actually SmartGWT) for an application on a Macintosh that communicates a lot with a database on a remote server but that also occasionally has to access local resources (e.g. some hardware on the computer or communicating with a word processing application).

I'm considering a browser-based approach (rather than a stand-alone approach using Cocoa) because (a) Smart GWT would nicely handle the remote communication and (b) this approach would make it easier to port my application to Windows in the future.

Given that I'll have administrator rights on the local machine, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please specify what do you mean under 'local' - local on server, or local on user's computer which opens your web application in browser ?

Answer (score 2):

GWT runs in a Web browser, so plain GWT or SmartGWT won't have permission to access resources on local computer (the one with browser). But you could use embedded applet which would proxy your requests to local system. You can see this concept described in [this article](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/09/pictarine-pictures-in-cloud.html), though in a bit different use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it server-side vie RPC and serialize the response. Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/apis.html#anchor3) for help with communicating via usb with java.